# React Material ui FilledInput cannot focus input when change state with onFocus event

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

trying to change state with onFocus event along side inputComponent
but when clicking on the input its losing is focus and need to click again to focus it

```
const TestInput = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(false);
  const customInput = React.useCallback(
    ({ inputRef, ...props }) => (
      <div>
        {state}
        <input ref={inputRef} {...props} />
      </div>
    ),
    [state]
  );
  return (
    <FilledInput
      inputComponent={customInput}
      onBlur={(e) => {
        console.log("onBlur");
      }}
      onFocus={(e) => {
        console.log("onFocus");
        setState(true);
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-grass-76xxf)

Answer (score 0):

The customInput only works when the value of state changes. Since the initialised value is false and only when the onFocus method is invoked, the state changes to True. This is why the double-click is needed to have the vertical-cursor visible.

Initialising the state value to true seems to be the solution here.

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState(true);
```

Comment: its never mind if is set to true or false first 
any change for state will cus the input to rerender and it will lose focus 

my question is how to change state (any state) and keep the input focused